# Copiar os arquivos de um remote para outro usando GIT

Tags: git, github, heroku

Eu tenho dois remotes configurados, o origin (repositório no heroku) e o github (repositório no github).
No meu repositório local eu fiz diversas alterações porém eu dava o "push" apenas no origin, deixando o github sem atualizações e commits.
Agora eu gostaria de saber como faço para que eu "copie" o origin (heroku) direto pro github.

Os passos que eu fiz foram o seguinte:

```
git clone git@heroku.com:meurepo.git meurepo
cd meurepo
heroku create
git remote add github git@github.com:meuusuario/meurepo.git
git push github
```

De início ele dizia que não havia dados a atualizar e que o repositório já estava atualizado mas eu sabia que não. Após alguns comandos como `git remote update` eu tentei dar novamente `git push github` e agora aparece o seguinte erro:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:rodrigokiller/speedup.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Tentei dar o `git pull` porém o mesmo erro aparece (de [rejected]).

Comment: Como foi seu pull? Você precisa definir o remoto e branch no comando `git pull github master`

Comment: meu pull foi `git pull github master`.

Comment: Se eu der um `git push --force github master` há algum problema?

Answer (score 1):

Apenas defina o novo `remote` e dê um `push` para o mesmo.

```
git remote add <nome do novo remote> <url do novo remote>
git push <nome do novo remote> <url do novo remote>
```

Comment: Ah, veja bem, foi isso que fiz, conforme no post inicial.

Comment: Tente dar um `git checkout` para o novo branch, um `git pull -u <nome do branch>` e, então, um `push`.

Answer (score 1):

Fiquei receoso quanto à tentar corrigir o `git pull github master` pois pelo que entendo, o pull "baixa" pro repositório local, e como o remote do github estava desatualizado, preferi optar pelo comando que eu também estava receoso:

`git push --force github master`.

Ao utilizar este comando, deu certo e parece que as novas alterações agora estão indo para os dois remotes (claro, dando um push em cada um separadamente).

Comment: O que parece que aconteceu é que seu branch local divergiu do branch remoto no GitHub. O `push --force` "sobrescreve" o branch remoto com o branch local. Se o efeito desejado é esse, de forçar o branch remoto a ficar igual ao local essa é a solução correta, mas note que essa divergência de branches pode ser decorrência de outro colaborador ter publicado commits na branch remota que não foram puxados pro seu repositório local. Nesse caso necessita-se realizar um merge (ou rebase) dos commits novos pra depois publicar sua branch local.